# Formatting text in dynamicaly created textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery that generates textareas with different id's. Now i need to make some buttons that will format text inside that textareas. For example: when user clicks in certain textarea, enter text, and click "bold" button, only text inside of that textarea will become bold (in other will be normal). I did manage to make something like this with JS, but it was too primitive (text was formated in all of textboxes) :(
Here is some sample code for this:

```
<button id="bold">B</button>
<textarea id="ta_1">Some test text</textarea>
<textarea id="ta_2">Some test text</textarea>
```

What i want to say: one button, multiply text boxes. Entering text in ta_1 and clicking bold, should bold only text in that txtarea. Additional info: all id's starting with same word, just different number at the end.

I feel there is some simple solution, just cant figure it out :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is a really bad practice, but you can do that like this,

```
var activeEl;

$("textarea").focus(function() {
  activeEl = $(this);
});

$("#bold").click(function() {
  $("textarea").css("font-weight", "");
  activeEl.css("font-weight","bold");
});
```

​
​
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CXzFv/1)

**UPDATE-1:** I don't know why you are trying to do this, but I suggest to you use a WYSIWYG Editor like [elRTE](http://elrte.org/)

**UPDATE-2** : You can costomize your toolbar in elRTE, if you want your editor has just a "bold" button, yes you can do that,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    elRTE.prototype.options.panels.web2pyPanel = ['bold'];
    elRTE.prototype.options.toolbars.web2pyToolbar = ['web2pyPanel'];
    var opts = {
        toolbar: 'web2pyToolbar',
    }
    var rte = $('#our-element').elrte(opts);
});​
```

[DEMO FOR elRTE](http://jsfiddle.net/T7vtW/)

Comment: Bad practice or not, this is the only way I can feasibly think of doing this. If there is another, I'd definitely want to know about it. For science!

Comment: Well, i am trying to do this, becouse i need editor that is not "attached" to every textarea, it would be great to have editor with "tool panel" that can be put anywhere, and not strictly above or below textarea. And also, i dont need all rich text functions, editors usualy have too much of it. I will try to implement answers in my code, and i will let you know if it works.

Comment: @DzoniTheJohnny, most of WYSIWYG Editor lets developers to customize their toolbar, also you can do that with elRTE as [mentioned here](http://elrte.org/redmine/projects/elrte/wiki/Docs_EN#Toolbar)

Comment: Well, i just cant get this code to work (jquery bold) with my dynamicaly generated content. If i normaly put textarea, it works, but when i genereate textarea with jquery, it wont work. Here is code i use for generating textareas (with different ids): http://pastebin.com/7WbdHfM8 . Ofc, i tried to remove all surounding divs (when genrating textarea), but nothing, keep getting this error in Opera JS debuger: http://pastebin.com/zCpqShvX

Answer (score 0):

Use document.activeElement

```
var activeEl;
$('#bold').mousedown(function()
{
     activeEl = document.activeElement

});
$("#bold").click(function() {

  //check activeElement
  if(......){
      activeEl .css("font-weight","bold");
  }
});
```

Don't forget check that activeElement exactly textarea

Comment: after the click, the `<button>` will be the active element

Comment: Oh, yes. then need to memorise last textarea focus

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a great idea for user functionality, but it can be done. You'll just need to record the "active textarea" somwhere. I would suggest using `.data()`. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzVKF/12/)

```
//disable the button until we have a target textarea to avoid confusion
$('#bold').attr('disabled','disabled');

//Record a new 'activeElement' each time user focuses a textarea
$('textarea').focus(function(e){
    $('#bold').data('activeElement',e.target)
        .removeAttr('disabled');//this first time we will enable the bold button
});

//retrieve the stored 'activeElement' and do something to it
$('#bold').click(function(){
    var activeElement = $('#bold').data('activeElement');
    $(activeElement).css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

Most people expect a "text formatting" button to work on their selection. Selections and ranges are out of the perview of jQuery and quite complicated to work with. As has been suggested already, I would advise using one of the many wonderful WYSIWYGs like [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).